# LucasChess won't start or install after update to 22.04 claiming "no antialiasing" key in org.gnome.settings

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dconf

I used LucasChess for a long time on previous installations, and never experienced any problems installing or running it. However, now on Ubuntu 22.04 it won't install or my previous installation of it won't start.
Running the installer (or the previously installed binary) from CLI delivers that output:

`jochen@ThinkPad-T520:~/Downloads$ ./LucasChessR2_02a_LINUX.sh
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing Lucas Chess R 2.02a  100%

./setup_linux.sh: 3: [[: not found
(setup_linux:5283): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 08:59:54.841: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' does not contain a key named 'antialiasing'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

And really, dconf-editor shows no such key.
However: Following a hint from developer Lukas Monk (who has no explanation nor solution to this behaviour) I found that running it with `sudo`works?!?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I've asked in a Ubuntu-Forum. They told me to go to the login-screen (just log off). You'll find settings in the lower right corner. Switch to "Ubuntu on XOrg" and then login again. Now it works.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH INDEED!
That really does the trick!